# series.unique vs list of set - performance

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have a pandas data frame with multiple columns. The aim is to find unique values in one of those columns.

Two ways to achieve this are:

- Get a list of set of that series: `list(set(data['Day']))`
- Get uniques using pandas's functions `data['Day'].unique()`

In my trials, `set` method works faster. Is this true for most cases? Why and why not? Any other resources utilization implication?

Please also add reasons to why either of them works better.

Comment: How have you tested this?

Comment: which dtype has `Day` column?

Comment: I used a CSV file with ~2.5m rows with 15 unique values in the column that I am trying to get uniques of. The datatype for column is the string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It will depend on the data type.  For numeric types, `pd.unique` should be significantly faster.

For strings, which are stored as python objects, there will be a much smaller difference, and `set()` will usually be competitive, as it is doing a very similar thing.

Some examples:

```
strs = np.repeat(np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='O'), 10000)

In [11]: %timeit pd.unique(strs)
558 µs ± 16.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit list(set(strs))
531 µs ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

nums = np.repeat(np.array([1, 2, 3]), 10000)

In [13]: %timeit pd.unique(nums)
230 µs ± 9.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit list(set(nums))
2.16 ms ± 71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Could you add a reason as to why `set` method is faster on strings? Even if nominally. Thanks!

Comment: `27 µs` isn't exactly a significant difference.  Both methods are looping through the python objects, constructing a hash table, then extracting a list of unique based on that table.  Differences would be due to relative overhead at different points.

Answer (score 8):

It makes sense to use categorical dtype for the columns that have few unique values.

Demo:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['aa','bbbb','c','ddddd','EeeeE','xxx'], 10**6), columns=['Day'])

In [34]: %timeit list(set(df['Day']))
98.1 ms ± 2.96 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [35]: %timeit df['Day'].unique()
82.9 ms ± 56.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

almost the same timing for 1M rows

Let's test category dtype:

```
In [37]: df['cat'] = df['Day'].astype('category')

In [38]: %timeit list(set(df['cat']))
93.7 ms ± 766 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [39]: %timeit df['cat'].unique()
25.1 ms ± 6.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**UPDATE:** 500 unique values in 1.000.000 rows DF:

```
In [75]: a = pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, 500)

In [76]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Day':np.random.choice(a, 10**6)})

In [77]: df.shape
Out[77]: (1000000, 1)

In [78]: df.Day.nunique()
Out[78]: 500

In [79]: %timeit list(set(df['Day']))
55 ms ± 395 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [80]: %timeit df['Day'].unique()
133 ms ± 3.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [81]: df['cat'] = df['Day'].astype('category')

In [82]: %timeit list(set(df['cat']))
102 ms ± 3.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [83]: %timeit df['cat'].unique()
38.3 ms ± 1.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Conclusion:** it's always better to "timeit" on your real data - you might have different results...

Comment: Interesting. Though it poses the questions as to what is a good number for "few unique values". Though in my case it will be more than 100s, yet its a helpful suggestion for certain cases.

Comment: @Wen, i tested `%timeit np.unique(df['Day'].values)[0]` - it took `2.51 s`

Comment: Hey @MaxU, I see. Do you have core reasons as to why these behaviors do happen? Also, since transformation to the category is giving a boost only to .unique function, you should time it using the combination of transformation and unique vs plain list of the set of series. Makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

The result seems to be varying highly on the number of unique entries:

Here is some time-testing on ipl dataset (deliveries)

For column match_id with 577 unique ids: unique() seems to be very efficient

```
%timeit list(set(deliveries['match_id']))
27.5 ms ± 2.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit deliveries['match_id'].unique()
1.79 ms ± 322 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For column batting_team with 13 unique teams: list(set()) slightly better here

```
%timeit list(set(deliveries['batting_team']))
9.92 ms ± 945 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit deliveries['batting_team'].unique()
10.2 ms ± 315 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Edit: Trying to test the string theory. Running the same tests on a string column batsman with 436 unique entries

```
%timeit list(set(deliveries['batsman']))
9.32 ms ± 431 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit deliveries['batsman'].unique()
8.06 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you aware of the reason behind this behavior? If so, could you please add it to the answer? Thanks.